# Stream has already been read and end-of-file reached and cannot be re-used

Tags: java, database, blob, derby

I have created a Derby database, created a table containing a BLOB column 'pic' as one of the columns.

Now I am trying to store .jpg file from local to this BLOB field.
I have written the code below, where I am trying to update BLOB column of every row with a local Image and then read the table once again and fetch the BLOB and store back on folder on local.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        String dbURL = "jdbc:derby:D:/software/derby/derby/bin/MyDbTest";
        Connection conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
        if (conn1 != null) {
            System.out.println("Connected to database #1");
        }
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn1
                .prepareStatement("update PRACTICEEMPLOYEEDB set pic = ?");
        File f1  =new File(
                "D:\\Users\\abkale\\Downloads\\asd.jpg");
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);
        stmt.setBinaryStream(1, in,f1.length());
        stmt.execute();   //LINE 1 :Place where exception in being thrown
        conn1.commit();

        Statement s = conn1.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs1=s.executeQuery("select * from practiceemployeedb");
        int i=0;
        while(rs1.next()){
            //Some code to read columns and print/store
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

But in above code i am getting below error on `//LINE 1` ::

```
Connected to database #1
java.sql.SQLException: An unexpected exception was thrown
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.executeStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at derby.ConnectionProvider.main(ConnectionProvider.java:33)
Caused by: ERROR XSDA4: An unexpected exception was thrown
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Stream has already been read and end-of-file reached and cannot be re-used.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.types.RawToBinaryFormatStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.MemByteHolder.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.RememberBytesInputStream.fillBuf(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.StoredPage.logColumn(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.StoredPage.logRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.UpdateOperation.writeOptionalDataToBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.UpdateOperation.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.LoggableActions.actionUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.StoredPage.doUpdateAtSlot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BasePage.updateAtSlot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.conglomerate.GenericConglomerateController.replace(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.RowChangerImpl.updateRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.UpdateResultSet.collectAffectedRows(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.UpdateResultSet.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericPreparedStatement.executeStmt(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

**I don't understand what I am doing wrong can anyone help?**

Comment: Slightly off topic, but `conn` cannt possibly be null at the point you're testing it.

Comment: Does the file exist? Can you use your stream somewhere else with success?

Comment: @BlueMoon93 If the file didn't exist a `FileNotFoundException` would have been thrown and the stack trace posted here would have been unreachable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot update multiple rows with the same stream. Create a where clause to select a single row in your statement and it should work.

This bug was reported to only fail with the embedded driver, and working with the client driver. More [info](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-2111) here.

Also, according to [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-6681), this problem only affects versions 10.9.1.0 and 10.10.2.0. Has this resurfaced on a later version or are you using one of these?

Comment: To be specific, a WHERE clause that selects a single row.

Comment: Thanks @BlueMoon93 that was the problem.

Comment: @EJP True. Edited for accuracy